# Smooth vertices option not working in blender 2.82

Tags: modeling, vertices, selection-tools

So This "Smooth vertices" tool That I use alot while modeling a character seem to not work any more or it just does not give the right result in the new update.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you have done, but I recently was trying to add weight to all objects and nothing worked and that was due to a selection mask being selected yet no objects selected. In *Sculpt Mode* the following picture shows how I can smooth **any** object

[image]

In the following picture only the selected stroke is edited. If, like me, you don't have any strokes selected, then you will not be able to edit.

[image]

Comment: Hmm I think I didn't quite explain  properly it is actually in edit mode.when you need to smooth some surface that tool does not work.

Comment: Ah appologies, that seems to work for me in 2.82.7. NB all I tried was creating a circle, selected every second vertex, moved them to form a 'jaggered' circle, selected all verticies, then when I did 'Smooth Verticies' and it put things back into a circle.

Comment: It seem to work now thanks